# Set Maximum Value for Lower Range of Google Number Range Filter

Tags: javascript, controls, google-visualization, trendline

I have a interactive Google Line Chart that displays historical sea level data between two different years as selected by the user.  The chart also displays both a linear and polynomial trendline for the selected period.  The available historical data ranges between the years 1904 to 2018 inclusive.  However the user can select any start year and end year from 1904 to 2120 inclusive.  If a end year beyond 2018 is selected, the chart displays the available historical data up to 2018 and then extends both trendlines to show the predicted sea level up to the year selected by the user.

This seems to work ok until both selected years exceed 2018, i.e. 2020 and 2056 when an error is thrown ("Cannot read property 'top' of null") because it can't calculate and draw a trendline from a period containing no observed data.  At the moment I'm getting around this with an error handler that picks up when this happens and shows an alert message advising the user they can't select a start year greater than 2018.  The page then reloads and the number range filter defaults back to the start and end year of 1904 and 2018 respectively, which is not ideal.  What I would like to do is restrict the user from selecting a start year that doesn't exceed 2018, but there doesn't seem to be an option/setting in the number range filter control to do this.  Any ideas?

My Code:

```
<html>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(initialize);

function initialize() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vn1iuhsG33XzFrC4QwkTdUnxOGdcPQOj-cuaEZeX-eA/edit#gid=0');
  query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  //Asign units of 'mm' to data.
  var formatMS = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '# mm'
  });

  // format data into mm.
  for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex < data.getNumberOfColumns(); colIndex++) {
    formatMS.format(data, colIndex);
  }
  var YearPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      maxValue:2120,
      filterColumnLabel: 'Year',
      ui: {
        cssClass: 'filter-date',
        format: {pattern: '0000'},
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    },
    "state": {"lowValue": 1904, "highValue": 2018},
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(YearPicker, 'statechange', filterChange);

  var MSLChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      fontSize: '14',
      title: 'Timbucktoo Annual Mean Sea Level Summary',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '0000'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Height above Chart Datum (mm)', format:'###0'},
      height: 600,
      chartArea: {height: '81%', width: '85%', left: 100},
      legend: {position: 'in', alignment: 'end', textStyle: {fontSize: 13}},
      colors: ['blue'],
      trendlines: {
        0: {
          type: 'polynomial',
          degree: 2,
          color: 'green',
          visibleInLegend: true,
        },
        1: {
          type: 'linear',
          color: 'black',
          visibleInLegend: true,
        },
      },
      series: {
        0: { visibleInLegend: true },
        1: { visibleInLegend: false },
      },
    },
    view: {columns: [0,1,2]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart, 'ready', filterChange);

  function filterChange() {
    // get chart layout
    var chartLayout = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface();

    // get y-axis bounds
    var yAxisCoords = {min: null, max: null};
    var lineIndex = 0;
    var boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);
   try {
    do {
      yAxisCoords.max = yAxisCoords.max || boundsLine.top;
      yAxisCoords.max = Math.min(yAxisCoords.max, boundsLine.top);
      yAxisCoords.min = yAxisCoords.min || (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height);
      yAxisCoords.min = Math.max(yAxisCoords.min, (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height));
      lineIndex++;
      boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);
    } while (boundsLine !== null);
     }
     catch (error) {alert("Please choose a start year less than or equal to 2018");
     window.location.reload(false);
     exit;
     }
    var state = YearPicker.getState();
      var EndYear = state.highValue;
    // re-draw chart
    MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', chartLayout.getVAxisValue(yAxisCoords.max));
    MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', chartLayout.getVAxisValue(yAxisCoords.min));
    MSLChart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', EndYear);
    MSLChart.draw();
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart.getChart(), 'ready', filterChange);
    }

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div')
  ).bind(YearPicker, MSLChart).draw(data);
}
</script>
  <div id="dashboard_div">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="filter_div"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to prevent the error, in the `filterChange` function,
change the `do...while` statement,

```
do {
  yAxisCoords.max = yAxisCoords.max || boundsLine.top;
  yAxisCoords.max = Math.min(yAxisCoords.max, boundsLine.top);
  yAxisCoords.min = yAxisCoords.min || (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height);
  yAxisCoords.min = Math.max(yAxisCoords.min, (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height));
  lineIndex++;
  boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);
} while (boundsLine !== null);
```

to just a `while` statement

```
while (boundsLine !== null) {
  yAxisCoords.max = yAxisCoords.max || boundsLine.top;
  yAxisCoords.max = Math.min(yAxisCoords.max, boundsLine.top);
  yAxisCoords.min = yAxisCoords.min || (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height);
  yAxisCoords.min = Math.max(yAxisCoords.min, (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height));
  lineIndex++;
  boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);
};
```

`do...while` assumed there would always be at least one line drawn.

---

we cannot prevent the user from selecting a start year exceeding 2018,
but we can immediately reset the start year when they do.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(YearPicker, 'statechange', function () {
  var state = YearPicker.getState();
  state.lowValue = Math.min(2018, state.lowValue);
  YearPicker.setState({
    lowValue: state.lowValue,
    highValue: state.highValue
  });
  YearPicker.draw();
  filterChange();
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(initialize);

function initialize() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vn1iuhsG33XzFrC4QwkTdUnxOGdcPQOj-cuaEZeX-eA/edit#gid=0');
  query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  //Asign units of 'mm' to data.
  var formatMS = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '# mm'
  });

  // format data into mm.
  for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex < data.getNumberOfColumns(); colIndex++) {
    formatMS.format(data, colIndex);
  }
  var YearPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      maxValue: 2120,
      filterColumnLabel: 'Year',
      ui: {
        cssClass: 'filter-date',
        format: {pattern: '0000'},
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    },
    state: {lowValue: 1904, highValue: 2018},
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(YearPicker, 'statechange', function () {
    var state = YearPicker.getState();
    state.lowValue = Math.min(2018, state.lowValue);
    YearPicker.setState({
      lowValue: state.lowValue,
      highValue: state.highValue
    });
    YearPicker.draw();
    filterChange();
  });

  var MSLChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      fontSize: '14',
      title: 'Timbucktoo Annual Mean Sea Level Summary',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '0000'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Height above Chart Datum (mm)', format:'###0'},
      height: 600,
      chartArea: {height: '81%', width: '85%', left: 100},
      legend: {position: 'in', alignment: 'end', textStyle: {fontSize: 13}},
      colors: ['blue'],
      trendlines: {
        0: {
          type: 'polynomial',
          degree: 2,
          color: 'green',
          visibleInLegend: true,
        },
        1: {
          type: 'linear',
          color: 'black',
          visibleInLegend: true,
        },
      },
      series: {
        0: { visibleInLegend: true },
        1: { visibleInLegend: false },
      },
    },
    view: {columns: [0,1,2]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart, 'ready', filterChange);

  function filterChange() {
    // get chart layout
    var chartLayout = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface();

    // get y-axis bounds
    var yAxisCoords = {min: null, max: null};
    var lineIndex = 0;
    var boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);

    while (boundsLine !== null) {
      yAxisCoords.max = yAxisCoords.max || boundsLine.top;
      yAxisCoords.max = Math.min(yAxisCoords.max, boundsLine.top);
      yAxisCoords.min = yAxisCoords.min || (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height);
      yAxisCoords.min = Math.max(yAxisCoords.min, (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height));
      lineIndex++;
      boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);
    };

    var state = YearPicker.getState();
    var EndYear = state.highValue;

    // re-draw chart
    MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', chartLayout.getVAxisValue(yAxisCoords.max));
    MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', chartLayout.getVAxisValue(yAxisCoords.min));
    MSLChart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', EndYear);
    MSLChart.draw();
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart.getChart(), 'ready', filterChange);
  }

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div')
  ).bind(YearPicker, MSLChart).draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

there are no options for modifying the tooltip for the trendline,
but we can change it manually, during the `'onmouseover'` event.

first, we need to use html tooltips, they are svg by default.
add this option...

```
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: true
  },
```

then add the `'onmouseover'` event to the chart,
we can do this in the `'ready'` event of the wrapper.

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart, 'ready', function () {
  google.visualization.events.addListener(MSLChart.getChart(), 'onmouseover', function (props) {
    // ensure trendline tooltip
    if ((props.column === 0) && (props.row !== null)) {
      // get year value
      var year = MSLChart.getDataTable().getValue(props.row, 0);

      // get tooltip, remove width
      var tooltip = MSLChart.getChart().getContainer().getElementsByTagName('ul');
      tooltip[0].parentNode.style.width = null;

      // get tooltip labels
      var tooltipLabels = MSLChart.getChart().getContainer().getElementsByTagName('span');

      // set year
      tooltipLabels[0].innerHTML = year;

      // remove formula
      tooltipLabels[1].innerHTML = '';

      // set height value
      var height = parseFloat(tooltipLabels[2].innerHTML.split(' ')[2].replace(',', '')).toFixed(0);
      tooltipLabels[2].innerHTML = height + ' mm';
    }
  });
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(initialize);

function initialize() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vn1iuhsG33XzFrC4QwkTdUnxOGdcPQOj-cuaEZeX-eA/edit#gid=0');
  query.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response) {

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  //Asign units of 'mm' to data.
  var formatMS = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '# mm'
  });

  // format data into mm.
  for (var colIndex = 1; colIndex < data.getNumberOfColumns(); colIndex++) {
    formatMS.format(data, colIndex);
  }
  var YearPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      maxValue: 2120,
      filterColumnLabel: 'Year',
      ui: {
        cssClass: 'filter-date',
        format: {pattern: '0000'},
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false
      }
    },
    state: {lowValue: 1904, highValue: 2018},
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(YearPicker, 'statechange', function () {
    var state = YearPicker.getState();
    state.lowValue = Math.min(2018, state.lowValue);
    YearPicker.setState({
      lowValue: state.lowValue,
      highValue: state.highValue
    });
    YearPicker.draw();
    filterChange();
  });

  var MSLChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      fontSize: '14',
      title: 'Timbucktoo Annual Mean Sea Level Summary',
      hAxis: {title: 'Year', format: '0000'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Height above Chart Datum (mm)', format:'###0'},
      height: 600,
      chartArea: {height: '81%', width: '85%', left: 100},
      legend: {position: 'in', alignment: 'end', textStyle: {fontSize: 13}},
      colors: ['blue'],
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
      trendlines: {
        0: {
          type: 'polynomial',
          degree: 2,
          color: 'green',
          visibleInLegend: true,
        },
        1: {
          type: 'linear',
          color: 'black',
          visibleInLegend: true,
        },
      },
      series: {
        0: { visibleInLegend: true },
        1: { visibleInLegend: false },
      },
    },
    view: {columns: [0,1,2]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart, 'ready', filterChange);

  function filterChange() {
    // get chart layout
    var chartLayout = MSLChart.getChart().getChartLayoutInterface();

    // get y-axis bounds
    var yAxisCoords = {min: null, max: null};
    var lineIndex = 0;
    var boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);

    while (boundsLine !== null) {
      yAxisCoords.max = yAxisCoords.max || boundsLine.top;
      yAxisCoords.max = Math.min(yAxisCoords.max, boundsLine.top);
      yAxisCoords.min = yAxisCoords.min || (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height);
      yAxisCoords.min = Math.max(yAxisCoords.min, (boundsLine.top + boundsLine.height));
      lineIndex++;
      boundsLine = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('line#' + lineIndex);
    };

    var state = YearPicker.getState();
    var EndYear = state.highValue;

    // re-draw chart
    MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', chartLayout.getVAxisValue(yAxisCoords.max));
    MSLChart.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', chartLayout.getVAxisValue(yAxisCoords.min));
    MSLChart.setOption('hAxis.viewWindow.max', EndYear);
    MSLChart.draw();
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart.getChart(), 'ready', filterChange);
  }

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(MSLChart, 'ready', function () {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(MSLChart.getChart(), 'onmouseover', function (props) {
      // ensure trendline tooltip
      if ((props.column === 0) && (props.row !== null)) {
        var year = MSLChart.getDataTable().getValue(props.row, 0);

        // get tooltip, remove width
        var tooltip = MSLChart.getChart().getContainer().getElementsByTagName('ul');
        tooltip[0].parentNode.style.width = null;

        // get tooltip labels
        var tooltipLabels = MSLChart.getChart().getContainer().getElementsByTagName('span');

        // set year
        tooltipLabels[0].innerHTML = year;

        // remove formula
        tooltipLabels[1].innerHTML = '';

        // set height
        var height = parseFloat(tooltipLabels[2].innerHTML.split(' ')[2].replace(',', '')).toFixed(0);
        tooltipLabels[2].innerHTML = height + ' mm';
      }
    });
  });

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div')
  ).bind(YearPicker, MSLChart).draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's wonderful @WhiteHat.  Really appreciate it.  Is there any way to hide the equation in the tooltip of each trendline and just show the year and sea level height instead?  Given the trendline equation is already shown in the legend, I feel it just convolutes and complicates the tooltip making it harder for the layman to understand.  Also, is it possible to show the year and height in the trendline tooltip as integers without commas and decimal points, like it's shown in the tooltip of the observed data, i.e. "2029: 1962 mm", instead of "2029.826: 1962.449"?

Comment: Thank you @Whitehat.  Just had to read through the Google Charts Tooltips guide to try and follow what you've done.  A couple of questions:

  1.  When you mouse over the legend it produces an error?
  2.  When you select a start and end year other than 1904 and 2018 and then mouse over any point on either trendline, the year that pops up in the tooltip doesn't match the year on the x-axis directly below the tooltip?

Comment: cheers, changed __EDIT__ above. __1.__ since the mouseover event fires on the legend, we need to ensure the row is not null --> `if ((props.column === 0) && (props.row !== null)) {` __2.__ to get the year value, we need to use the filtered data table from the chart wrapper --> `var year = MSLChart.getDataTable().getValue(props.row, 0);`

Comment: Thanks again @WhiteHat.  The year that pops up in the tooltip still doesn't match the year on the x-axis directly below the tooltip?  For example if you select 1904 and 2120, then mouse over either trendline directly above 2120 on the x-axis, the year returned in the tooltip is 2062 when it should be 2120.  I had a go at troubleshooting this myself but didn't get far.

Comment: hmm, I see. the above corrected the issue when hovering the series but not the trendline. let me think...

Comment: I noticed the year in the tooltip of both trend lines matches that directly below on the x axis when there is also observed data (blue line) for the year in question, i.e. 1904 - 2018.  So I tried inserting a new series with dummy data for the years 2019 - 2120 to see if it would realign the year that pops up in each trendline tooltip with that directly below it on the x-axis for this period. If this worked I was then going to try and hide this new dummy series by making the points invisible if possible.  It didn't work, but perhaps there is another workaround using this concept?

Comment: I did find another solution, but it also has problems. I'll post the latest version in a day or so, when I'm back in the office...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: after testing further, it has too many problems. you can use [chart method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) `getHAxisValue` to get the year value based on the mouse position over the chart. but I just found that after adjusting the year picker, the values are way off. plus, if you hover close to the trend line, but not directly over, the original tooltip is shown instead of the custom. [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndwgoqrk/)

Comment: No problem @WhiteHat.  I have genuinely really appreciated all your help.  I've had a bit of a play around myself today and have managed to get it working by removing `var year = MSLChart.getDataTable().getValue(props.row, 0);` and replacing it with `var year = parseFloat(tooltipLabels[0].innerHTML.split(' ')[0].replace(',', '')).toFixed(0);`.  This seems to produce the correct year in the tooltip, i.e. corresponds with the x-axis directly below.  A complete fluke.  I'm so chuffed.  My earlier offer still stands of a beer or two if you're ever in New Zealand.  Thanks again.

Comment: that's great, sometimes I get so far down a hole, I can't find my way back out. that should work just fine...